# numpy where condition on index

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy 1D array of numbers representing columns e.g: `[0,0,2,1]`
And a matrix e.g:

```
[[1,1,1],
[1,1,1],
[1,1,1],
[1,1,1]]
```

Now I a want to change the values in the matrix to 0 where the column index is bigger than the value given in the 1D array:

```
[[1,0,0],
[1,0,0],
[1,1,1],
[1,1,0]]
```

How can I achieve this? I think I need a condition based on the index, not on the value

Explanation:
The first row in the matrix has indices [0,0 ; 0,1 ; 0,2] where the second index is the column. For indices 0,0 ; 0,1 and 0,2 the value 0 is given. 1 and 2 are bigger than 0. Thus only 0,0 is not changed to zero.

Comment: Column index (2) is bigger than all values in column with index 2. Why don't you change all 1s to 0s then?

Comment: @zabop where the column **index** is bigger, for the first row [1,1,1] we have number 0. In this row we have the numbers with indices 0,0 ; 0,1 and 0,2 The first index does not have column >0, the others do. The 1 and 2 out of 0,1 and 0,2 are bigger than 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `a` the 2D array and `v` the 1D vector, you can create a mask of the same size and use `numpy.where`:

```
x,y = a.shape
np.where(np.tile(np.arange(y), (x,1)) <= v[:,None], a, 0)
```

Input:

```
a = np.array([[1,1,1],
              [1,1,1],
              [1,1,1],
              [1,1,1]])

v = np.array([0,0,2,1])
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0]])
```

Intermediates:

```
>>> np.tile(np.arange(y), (x,1))
[[0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]]

>>> np.tile(np.arange(y), (x,1)) <= v[:,None]
[[ True False False]
 [ True False False]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True False]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this works!  I accepted your answer, for the clear details, easy two liner and clear intermediate steps.

Answer (score 2):

Construct a 2D array whose elements are the corresponding column index, and then mask the elements greater than the corresponding value of the 1D array.

Taking advantage of  broadcasting, you can do:

```
>>> arr = np.ones((4,3))
>>> arr 

array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])

>>> col_thr_idx = np.array([0,0,2,1])
>>> col_thr_idx

array([0, 0, 2, 1])

>>> mask = np.arange(arr.shape[1])[None,:] > col_thr_idx[:,None]
>>> mask

array([[False,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True]])

>>> arr[mask] = 0
>>> arr

array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 0.]])
```